# connect mongoDb to nodejs on localhost

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to use mongoDB for my app.
I have 2 databases and use next code to connect:

```
var express = require("express");
var router  = express.Router();
var mongojs = require("mongojs");

//var mongo_db = 
//mongojs("mongodb://xxxxx:xxxxx@some_adress/cat_mean_db", ["tasks"]);

var mongo_db = mongojs("mongodb://xxxxx:xxxxx@localhost:3000/cat_db", 
["tasks"]);

//get all docs(pages)
router.get("/tasks", function (req, res, next ) {
mongo_db.tasks.find(function (error, tasks) {
    if(error)
        res.send(error);
    res.json(tasks);
});
});
```

if I use this db

```
var mongo_db = 
mongojs("mongodb://xxxxx:xxxxx@some_adress/cat_mean_db", 
["tasks"]);
```

everything is working well, but when I try to use db on localhost I got an `exeption: connection 0 to localhost:3000 closed`

the local db is exist and has user for shure.

Comment: Do not post passwords here please. And instead of placing links to images with code, paste the code here using the code button of the editor.

Comment: On the last piece of code I can see yet your password, and change the domain because it's not necessary here ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From mongoose documentation on NPM :

> Note: If the local connection fails then try using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. Sometimes issues may arise when the local hostname has been changed.

You should try using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.

Comment: thx for help but it doesnt work with 127.0.0.1 too, may be mongod is working on some other port, not the same as nodejs?

Comment: Ahaha, yes its great, oooh I, it really cant be on same port))) all work now i  use 27017 port as wrote in mongod console